# Apply Sister table value to All Parent/child relationships in main table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

BACKGROUND:

I have a rather complex scenario (at least to me) in that I want to return data from 2 tables where one of them contains a parent/child or hierarchy relationship and only some of the family members may be referenced from the other table.

Suppose I have 3 tables with data as follows:

TABLE 1 - Defines a parent/child relationship with a name.  Can be multiple levels, not just a parent and child, but full hierarchy

```
Id | Table1Name | ParentId
---------------------------
1  | Root       | NULL
2  | Child1     | 1
3  | Chile2     | 1
4  | Root2      | NULL
5  | Child1-2   | 4
6  | Child2-2   | 4
```

TABLE 2 - child table of TABLE 3 below.  Also references TABLE 1 above

```
Id | Table2Name | Table1Id | Table3Id
-------------------------------------------
20 | Test1      | 2        | 40
21 | Test2      | 2        | 40
22 | Test3      | 3        | 40
23 | Test4      | 3        | 40
24 | Test5      | 5        | 41
25 | Test6      | 5        | 41
26 | Test7      | 6        | 41
27 | Test8      | 6        | 41
```

TABLE 3 - Parent table - Just included as reference for this example, not used in query

```
Id | Table3Name
-----------------
40 | Parent1
41 | Parent2
```

ISSUE:

I'm trying to develop a query that will list ALL of the rows from TABLE 1, but will include the Table3Id that is associated with all entries for that parent/child relationship.  So for this example, I'm expecting a resultset that looks like the following:

```
Id | Table1Name | ParentId | Table3Id
--------------------------------------
1  | Root       | NULL     | 40
2  | Child1     | 1        | 40
3  | Chile2     | 1        | 40
4  | Root2      | NULL     | 41
5  | Child1-2   | 4        | 41
6  | Child2-2   | 4        | 41
```

Note that lines 1 and 4 above have no direct relationship to TABLE 2, but have an indirect relationship through lines (2 and 3) and (5 and 6) respectively.

I'm sure there is a way in which to do this, but I am blanking on the right combination of code in which to do so.

Comment: What should happen if you have a record in Table2 saying Table3Id for record 2 is 40 and for record 3 is 41. What should be the result for 2 & 3's parent, 1?

Comment: That's a good question that I meant to address in my question above, but forgot.  While it isn't apparent above, there will be business logic to prevent that scenario from happening.  So for all intensive purposes, assume that scenario could never exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a recursive CTE, starting with all children that have a match in Table2 and then move up in the tree.

```
WITH recHierarchy AS
(
    SELECT t1.Id, t1.ParentId, t2.Table3Id
      FROM #table1 t1
     INNER
      JOIN #table2 t2
        ON t1.Id = t2.Table1Id

     UNION ALL

     SELECT parent.Id, parent.ParentId, child.Table3Id
       FROM #table1 parent
       JOIN recHierarchy child
         ON child.ParentId = parent.Id
)
SELECT DISTINCT Id, ParentId, Table3Id FROM recHierarchy
```

This will also work if there is a hierarchy in Table1 like:

```
Id | Table1Name | ParentId
---------------------------
7  | Root3       | NULL
8  | Child3-1    | 7
9  | Chile3-1-1  | 8
```

And Table3Id is only defined on Id = 9.

[Working example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d35196424c8d3e80ee0bb72040cf0aab).

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer and the working example. That was exactly what I was looking for!  I was close on this, but was going in the reverse, starting with the parent and trying to get children which didn't work. Thank you again!